# How can getSelectConditionSQL() output a IN ('sonata.ecommerce_demo.product.travel') statement?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, e-commerce, sonata

I have a pending project with Sonata e-commerce, and need to understand how it works. I want to manager product variation in Doctrine/mongoDB while leaving all the other data to Doctrine/MySQL.
So I installed the sandbox with the demo part, and traced.

This led me to the ORM\Persiters\BasicEntityPersister which has a getSelectSQL() method.

When editing for instance a travel product `http://mysite/app_dev.php/admin/sonata/product/product/526/edit`, a $conditionSql variable got the following sql condition assigned:

> t0.id = ? AND t0.product_type IN ('sonata.ecommerce_demo.product.travel')

When I output the getSelectConditionSQL() method before the return, I have

> t0.id = ?

So, the question is : Where is the `AND t0.product_type IN ('sonata.ecommerce_demo.product.travel')` part generated, and most of all, where does the IN() statement come from?

I really have to know because when I try and put a Document as a param,

```
<service id="sonata.ecommerce_demo.product.travel.manager" class="Sonata\ProductBundle\Document\ProductManager">
        <argument>Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Document\Travel</argument>
        <argument type="service" id="doctrine_mongodb" />
    </service>
```

I end up with an empty IN() statement.

Thks to any help…

Comment: Does your `Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Document\Travel` class extends some other one?

Comment: Nope. I can make it extend an Entity class like Product (the `Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Travel\Travel` extends the `Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Document\Product` class). But I guess it is not relevant to extend an Entity class with a Document class. I think I'll have to write something to bind them, though I don't exactly know how to do it by now.

Comment: Besides, when I extend the Entity/Product class with Document/Travel, I have a `The class 'Application\Sonata\ProductBundle\Document\Travel' was not found in the chain configured namespaces` error, which seems fair to me because all the possible listed namespaces in the error message are entities…